# Getting white screen while adding user roles from backend in Magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am getting white screen when I try to add user roles from backend of Magento. I am using Magento 1.9.2.2. After inspecting the backend, here is the issue I found.

```
 Array
  (
    [type] => 1
    [message] => Class 'Mage_Defer_Helper_Data' not found
    [file] => /chroot/home/beverlyh/beverlyhillsliquorandwine.com/html/app/Mage.php
    [line] => 547
 )
```

Any solutions? I am unable to find this relevant class in Magento.

Comment: As far as I know, that class isn't a default Magento helper, so it sounds like you've got a defer extension that's not defining the helper classes correctly, look through your code for any module, (app/etc/modules) and see if there's any extensions that look like they have defer in there name.

Comment: @PhilS: Thanks PhilS for directing me to right path , however its was not cacheing extension or defer extension . but it was Signifyd extension causing problem .

Comment: If you resolved the issue post it as an answer